# Nested get performance

Tags: java

In Java, is there a performance hit if i continually use nested get to retrieve values? For instance:

```
String firstname = getOffice().getDepartment().getEmployee().getFirstName();
String lastname = getOffice().getDepartment().getEmployee().getLastName();
String address = getOffice().getDepartment().getEmployee().getAddress();
```

VS:

```
Employee e = getOffice().getDepartment().getEmployee();
String firstname = e.getFirstName();
String lastname = e.getLastName();
String address = e.getAddress();
```

Would the 2nd version be faster because it has less 'jumps'?

Comment: The word you are looking for is `chained` gets. Nesting implies that one get is happening within the context of another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends entirely on what the `getXYZ` calls **do**. If they're simple accessors to an underlying field, then no, not on HotSpot (Oracle's JVM), because they'll get optimized out if there's any need to do so. If, on the other hand, they do any kind of complex work (traversing a btree, etc.), then of course they'll have to do that work repeatedly (unless HotSpot can prove to itself that the calls are idempotent, which if the code has any complexity becomes unlikely). (Whether it *matters* that they do the work repeatedly is another question; until/unless you see an actual performance problem, don't worry about it.)

But the second is *much* more readable and maintainable. That's the more powerful reason for using it.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than performance I see `second as better human understandable code`. You should not worry about micro optimizations but write a good and clean code.

Answer (score 2):

The optimization you are thinking about is called [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). You should not think about these unless you really have to.

I agree with @AmitD's answer about being the second one more readable. When chaining method calls like this, you can also write them in the following way -

```
Employee e = getOffice()
              .getDepartment()
              .getEmployee();
String firstname = e.getFirstName();
String lastname = e.getLastName();
String address = e.getAddress();
```

to further improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly yes. But assuming the getters look like ordinary getters on the inside it will probably be so small that it becomes almost impossible to measure.

Also if you run through this code often enough to make it matter, the magic of the Hotspot compiler will kick in and mangle the byte code, probably again making both variations the same.

In the end it is extremely hard to tell what really will happen. If performance matters for you set up a test. If performance doesn't matter enough to justify the costs of the test ... well then it doesn't matter enough to worry.

Answer (score 0):

Either use byte code analysis or time the two approaches using `System.nanoTime`. I think second one is faster. here is what I did to conclude this:

I wrote three classes as given below:

```
public static class A {
    public B b = new B();
}

public static class B {
    public E e = new E();
}

public static class E {
    public String name = "s";
    public int age = 1;
}
```

Then I wrote two simple methods and get their java byte code using `javap -c CLASS_NAME`.

```
public static void Test1() {
    A a = new A();
    String str = a.b.e.name;
    int age = a.b.e.age;
}
```

The byte code of above method is:

```
public static void Test1();
    Code:
       // new A();
       0: new           #15
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #17                 
       7: astore_0      
       8: aload_0

       // a.b (it accesses the field and put it on operand stack)
       9: getfield      #18

      // b.e
      12: getfield      #22

      // b.name
      15: getfield      #28

      // pop 'name' from stack
      18: astore_1      
      19: aload_0  

      // cyle continues     
      20: getfield      #18
      23: getfield      #22
      26: getfield      #34 
      29: istore_2      
      30: return
```

You can clearly see at byte code level, each time you try to access field, it put the value of that filed on stack and then this cycle continues. Therefore, `a.a1.a2....an` would be `n` instruction if stack would have enough spae to hold all `n`. And there was no optimisation by compiler this same cycle of called again to access both `name` and `age` field.

Now here is the second method:

```
public static void Test2() {
        A a = new A();
        E e = a.b.e;
        String str = e.name;
        int age = e.age;
    }
```

Byte code for above method is:

```
public static void Test2();
    Code:
       // new A();
       0: new           #15 
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #17
       7: astore_0      
       8: aload_0       

       // store a.b.e on operand stack once
       9: getfield      #18
      12: getfield      #22
      15: astore_1      
      16: aload_1

      // get 'name' field
      17: getfield      #28
      20: astore_2      
      21: aload_1       
      // get 'age' field
      22: getfield      #34
      25: istore_3      
      26: return
```

Above is 4 instruction shorter than previous code as it prevents execution of `getfield`. So I think this should be faster than previous one.

Comment: Wow tks for the effort. Its quite an eye opener.

Comment: Remember, though, that the bytecode is only part of the story. The JVM can and will alter it at runtime. Oracle's JVM (HotSpot) will identify parts that get used a lot (hot spots) and aggressively optimize them. One of the simplest and easiest things for it to do is to inline simple accessors.